# jQuery attach mediaelement.js to dynamically created audio tags

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bind, mediaelement.js

I'm using the mediaelement.js plugin as my media player for HTML5 audio tags.

I attach the player to the tags using `$('audio, video').mediaelementplayer();` But I'd like to know how I can do this for dynamically created audio tags. Is there a solution like live or on like there is for events?

Comment: can you just re-run after you add the tags?

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't answer my question ;)

Comment: So I'm guessing this isn't possible?

Answer (score 2):

When you create the audio element dynamically can you create the mediaelement at the same time?

```
var audio = my new audio element

var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#id of new audio element',/* Options */);
// ... more code ...
player.pause();
player.setSrc('mynewfile.mp3');
player.play();
```

etc.

Comment: Yes but this is the same as calling 
$('audio, video').mediaelementplayer(); a second time. I want to know if there is a way I can only call this code once, just like I can for events using bind/live/on etc. :)